# Expression brain fade

Tags: c#, c++, logic

I'm having brain fade trying to write a single logical expression that suits the question's comment

```
// **Don't do xyz between 10.00pm and 7:30am**
//
if(hour > 22 || (hour < 7 && minutes < 30)
    output("too early or too late");
```

Without coming up with something god awful like:

```
if (hour > 20)
    "Too late";

if (hour < 7)
    "Too early"
else
if (hour == 7 && minute < 30)
          "Too early"
```

Please put me out of my misery.

Comment: Pick a language please, choosing two doesn't help anyone...

Comment: @DavidG my bad, I mistook the name of a function he mentioned for a C library function name. I'll revert my edit.

Comment: I put it under C# and C++ to get the best possible coverage - syntax the same in both.

Comment: The answer might not be the same syntax though, don't choose a tag for coverage, choose it for appropriateness.

Comment: `if` statement is the same in a lot of languages. C# and C++ are two very different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` is your friend here.  If you have multiple conditions and if any of them are true you want to do something then instead of using

```
if (condition1)
    do_something();
if (condition2)
    do_something();
if (condition3)
    do_something();
```

You can use

```
if (condition1 || condition2 || condition3)
    do_something();
```

So to relate that to what you have your single if statement would be

```
if(hour > 21 || hour < 7 || (hour == 7 && minute < 30))
    output("too early or too late");
```

Comment: Try 22 hour and 10 minutes, as in 22:10.

Comment: @Equalsk Well that depends on  what the OP wants.  If they want any time after 22:00 then they just need `hour > 21`.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what OP wants, any time before 7:30 and after 22:00 is not OK. The only question I'd have is whether this is inclusive of these times, but 22:10 should definitely not pass and it does in your sample...

Comment: @Equalsk I missed the comment in the code so I didn't see that requirement.  Updated the answer.